# CSS width/height of IMG and TD

Tags: html, css, parsing, height, width

> I have a problem in css, I have a TD with a width:100px; and height:100px; inside it, I have an img element with the same width and height (100px, 100px). 
>   The problem is that the TD is automatically resized to 145px width and 114 px height.
>
> If anyone know why, and how to solve it please help me! (it would be great if I did not need no increase my TD's size, my image must be 100*100)
>   This problem has been fixed, I had commented that part of the css. But my image is now placed under my text in titleTD and descTD.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="pixelContent">
        <table id="pixelContentTable">
        <tr valign=center>
            <td id="imageTD" rowspan=2>
                <a href=""><img src="" id="contentImage" border="0" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>
            <td id="titleTd">Title here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign=center>
            <td id="descTd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://google.com"> nunc in sapien gravida</a> eleifend. Maecenas consectetur, risus id lobortis molestie, magna sapien ullamcorper justo, ultrices </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#pixelContentTable{
margin: 0 auto;
width:400px;
height:120px;
text-align:left;
}

#contentImage{
margin-left:10px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
min-width:100px;
min-height:100px;
max-width:100px;
max-height:100px;
}



  #imageTD{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:100px;
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:100px;
  }
```

Comment: can we see all of your code?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: a fiddle = [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="" alt />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and CSS:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/otaFb

Comment: display: block - is main thing!